# PlaceHolderAPI not working

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

As part of my plugin i have a clear chat command and at the end of the blank messages there is an option to display text. My problem is that the PlaceHolderAPI isn't working as it should.

Command Code:

```
if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("clearchat") || label.equalsIgnoreCase("mcc")) {
    if (p.hasPermission("mystic.chat.admin.clearchat")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getConfig().getInt("clearChat.blankLines"); i++) {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(" ");
        }
        for (String s : getConfig().getStringList("clearChat.endMessage")) {
            s = PlaceholderAPI.setPlaceholders(p, s);
            // This is here to check if the PlaceHolderAPI even knows there is place holders in it
            p.sendMessage(String.valueOf(PlaceholderAPI.containsPlaceholders(s)));
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', s));

        }
        return true;
    } else {
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are lacking the required permission node!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Config File section:

```
clearChat:
  blankLines: 256
  endMessage:
  - '&bChat was cleared by %player_name%'
```

When i run the command "/mcc" or "/clearchat" it always says false (for not recognizing any placeholders) and none of the place holders are replaced.

I do have the API correctly in the build path, and the command words perfectly, other than the place holders not converting.

I feel as if im making a stupid mistake, or that im doing this the complete wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use another api using p.getName() should suffice then using String.replace to replace the %name%

Comment: [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be upvoted.

Comment: I want the user to be able to use all place holders within the API not just %name%

Answer (score 0):

You are using the API wrong
You did this

```
s = PlaceholderAPI.setPlaceholders(p, s);
```

If the API would throw an error if there are no placeholders just surround that line with a `try{} catch (Exception e)` then send it to the player

```
p.sendMessage(s);
```

There is no need for the String.valueOf(s) as the API [is expected to] return a String, anyways setting the `String s = PlaceholderAPI.setPlaceholders(p, s);` will cast whatever object is there to a string.

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain more? (sorry for really late reply)

Comment: For the first paragraph do this instead
    try{
       s = PlaceholderAPI.setPlaceholders(p, s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
For the second bit you dont need the
    String.valueOf(s)
because s is already a String and so would just return the exact same thing as s.